# @OneToMany lazy list throws NPE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem. Any time I want to call `train.getPath()` it throws `NPE`. Shouldn't those `trainEdges` be loaded due to first `getPath()` method?

I get `train` object through `getById(int id)`.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "trains")
public class Train {
    //fields
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "train")
    private List<TrainEdge> path;
    
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "trainPaths")
public class TrainEdge {
    //fields
    @JoinColumn(name = "train")
    @ManyToOne
    private Train train;
}
```

```
@Repository
public class TrainDaoImpl implements TrainDao {
    //Other methods
    
    @Override
    public Train getById(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(Train.class, id);
    }
```

Comment: The method calling getPath() must be @Transactional to ensure ability to call DB "on the fly"

Comment: @DanielZ. Unfortunately, I can't use Spring Data(

Comment: You don't need Spring Data to add Spring JPA Transactions